# Angular app working offline and sync

Tags: angularjs, indexeddb, offlineapps

We have gone down the route of using indexeddb as the store for our objects and then marking items with a flag to be synchronized back to the server once online again. Its been written in a fairly untidy manor at the moment and syncs whole objects back and forth which can cause performance issues and slow down.

I was wondering if anyone has implemented anything that just keeps track of deltas and synchronizes using this, perhaps a message queue or something like a change log that keeps track of individual field changes?

Comment: can you have some field like change-time & last-receive-time or something saying `IsDirty`

Comment: Yes, we have a modified date and a sync flag, but we'd have to keep track over every field in this way. I guess I'm looking for a good pattern to use for maintaining a change log of fields modified.
When our isdirty flag is set the whole object is sent over the wire, which is fine but what if other users have modified offline and sync back as well, who is right. Thats why I'm thinking change log.

Comment: maintaining it per field would be too much.. sorry I am no aware of any such framework and would be warry of doing this anyways...

Comment: Have been reading some good advice hear https://quickleft.com/blog/making-your-app-work-offline-tips-and-cautionary-tales/#comment-1953155849
Optimistic versioning might well be adequate for me

Comment: good blog... versioning is good enough but then thats per record not per field

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this a lot and created a project... The documentation for it is detailed and explains why and how... It may help, or at least give you things to think about. It has very recently been updated to support IndexedDB

https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt

There is also [RemoteStorage](https://github.com/remotestorage) ( they were/are looking at using SyncIt + other bits in the project going forward ), [Hood.ie](http://hood.ie/) and the commercial FireBase in this field.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will definitely take a look at that project

Comment: [RemoteStorage](https://github.com/remotestorage/remotestorage.js/tree/master/src) looks good too.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a vote or accept please :-)